# Why does visual studio not open my wxWidgets gui's window(frame)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, wxwidgets

I start a project where I use wxWidgets. There are 2 classes and 2 cpp files.
**1st class:**

```
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MainFrame:public wxFrame
{
public:
    MainFrame(const wxString& title);
};
```

**2nd class:**

```
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>

class App:public wxApp
{
public:
    bool onInit();
};
```

**1st cpp file:**

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "MainFrame.h"

using namespace std;

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title) :wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title) {

}
```

**2nd cpp file**

```
#include "App.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "MainFrame.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

bool App::onInit() {
    MainFrame* mainFrame = new MainFrame("main");
    mainFrame->Show();
    return true;
}
```

After starting debugging visual studio write about running my project's exe file without any errors or warnings, but doesn't open anything. That's why I have only one question, why?

I reopened tutorial and compared codes. They are identical. I trid to reopen visual studio, but I didn't get any changes

Comment: Did you tell VS to run the program or only to build it?

Comment: @БогданИванилов, can you open minimal_vcN.sln, build it and run it? It can be found in wxWidgets\samples\minimal directory... That is if you build the library yourself...

Comment: I have an `OnInit()` function that has a statement `mainFrame->Show(true);`.  Notice I'm passing the value `true`.

Comment: @Igor, yes i can

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I tell VS to run the program. After passing true, nothing has changed.

Comment: P.S. I tried to run program again and VS tell me thats it can't open project's exe file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the function needs to be `OnInit()` with a capital `O` in the beginning, because that is the name of the virtual function it is supposed to override. Your code samples have a lowercase `o` in the beginning.

This is exactly the kind of mistake that would not go unnoticed if the function was declared using the `override` keyword, i.e.

```cpp
bool onInit() override;
```

This way the compiler would issue an error about `onInit()` not overriding anything.